# React Apollo Client Resolver does not receive data from cache

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a playground React-App to display To Do items which I am migrating to Apollo Cache.
The problem I am facing is I want to create an 'intermediate graphql layer' on my client to handle operations on the client cache.

**The Problem**

I have a **proof-of-concept query** called **getItemCount** which returns the number of entries stored within the item array inside the cache.

Inside the **client-side resolver function**, I use the `cache` object to read a query (`cache.readQuery<any>(...)`).
This always seems to return an object with zero length rather than the acutal array stored within the cache.

**What I Want To Do**

I want to **query the apollo cache inside the client resolvers** in order to perform business logic related to local state and provide it in the form of custom graphql queries. 
The goal of this approach is to simplify adaption and reuse for other developers of the same applications.

**Remarks**

I am using Apollo DevTools to inspect my application and the query execution behavior at runtime.

The query seems to dispatch after the items array is fully populated by other business logic and stored within the cache. I can see the items being stored in the cache using the DevTools extension.

Moreover, there is other logic retreiving the items from cache as well and they work just as expected.

**Source Code**

I followed parts of the [Apollo Fullstack Tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/) to create some custom **client resolvers**.

```ts
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { ApolloCache } from "apollo-cache";
import { Resolvers } from "apollo-client";

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type ToDoItem {
    userId: Int!
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    completed: Boolean!
  }

  extend type Query {
    test: String!
    getItemCount: Int!
  }
`;

type ResolverFunction = (
  parent: any,
  args: any,
  { cache }: { cache: ApolloCache<any> }
) => any;

//this can contain as many resolver functions as possible
interface ResolverMap {
  [field: string]: ResolverFunction;
}


interface ClientResolvers extends Resolvers {
  Query: ResolverMap;
}

export const resolvers: ClientResolvers = {
  Query: {
    test(parent: any, _: any, { cache }) {
      return "Hello, World!";
    },
    getItemCount(parent: any, _: any, { cache }) {
      const GET_ITEMS = gql`
        query GetItems {
          items
        }
      `;

      const data = cache.readQuery<any>({
        query: GET_ITEMS,
      });

      if (!data) {
        return -1;
      }

      return data.items.length;
    }
  }
};
```

And in the App.tsx file I am initally **populating the cache** like so.

```ts
import React from "react";
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink } from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./Clients/ClientResolvers";

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: ""
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false
  }),
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

apolloClient.writeData({
  data: {
    searchValue: "",
    items: [
      {
        id: -1,
        userId: 2,
        title: "test",
        completed: true
      }
    ]
  }
});

//...
```

I have a custom hook that reads and writes items data to and from the cache by retreiving a client via `useApolloClient()` for write and utilizing `useQuery` for read. This works as expected.

However, when I make a graphql call to my custom resolver Queries (which actually DO work, mind the example query 'test'), the **getItemCount query always returns zero**. This indicates to me that the resolver can well find the cache object itself it always resolves to be empty.